# How do I find files with no extension in Finder?

Tags: mac, finder, spotlight, search

I'm trying to find all files that have no extension in a Finder folder.  I know how to search by extension and exclude a specific extension but what do I type in the box if I want no extension at all?

Comment: how can there be a file without extension (you mean it is not showing it?)

Comment: @Buscar웃 not every file requires an extension. For example Brewfiles or shell scripts don't need an extension like .sh or so.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a Finder search like this:

```
- None of the following is true:
- - Filename contains .
- - Kind is Folder
```

The Finder does however exclude some system items from search results. The same search criteria produced 19'077 search results in Finder and 131'666 in [HoudahSpot](http://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot).

Comment: Finer instructions for those who need it:  In Finder after pressing `⌘F` (Command-F) or typing in the search box, you'll get see search bar which has a `+` (Plus Sign) button on the far right. Click the `+` and a new bar of filter options will appear, with its own `+` button on the far right.  On your keyboard, hold down the `⌥` (Option key) and the `+` button will turn in to `⋯` (Ellipsis) now press that! Then you can add the `None` and additional filters mentioned above.  Here's an example:  https://i.imgur.com/YucSOrV.gif

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible in Catalina